# Wireless driver on macbook air early 2015

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom, macbook

So I have installed Ubuntu ony macbook air but can't seem to get the WiFi working. I followed the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers#60395) and [here](https://www.amirootyet.com/post/how-to-get-wifi-to-work-after/) but nothing seems to work. For reference, after running

```
lspci -vnn | grep Network
```

I get the output BCM4360 along with [14e4:43a0] rev3 which should correspond to the bcmwl-kernel-source command.

I tried running

```
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then rebooting to no avail. Then doing the same for firmware-b43-installer just to see if it worked. Neither did upon rebooting. Is there something I am missing? Thanks

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Glad you resolved your issue. Please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're using, as that will help others with similar issues in the future find your issue/resolution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it :D turns out version 23 of Ubuntu is wonky. As soon as I switched to the LTS version of Ubuntu everything worked fine.